# Target input with :focus, even when changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this in jQuery

```
if($("input").is(":focus")){
// do something
}
```

It has an effect on the focused input like it should. However, when I switch over to a new input that gets the focus instead, the first one is the still having that effect and not the new one. What would be a good way to make it auto update so that the one that is currently focused has the effect? Thanks!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: reason is simply because you said "do x when y happens". You didn't say "undo x when y is no longer true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Do something" on focus; "Undo that thing" on blur

Your example only runs one time and targets only one `input`: the one with focus. It doesn't respond to changes.

Use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind event listeners that can respond to changes.

**A basic example:**

```js
$('input').on('focus', function () {
  // do something
  $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});

$('input').on('blur', function () {
  // do something
  $(this).css('background-color','white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

**Another example using chaining:**

```js
$('input')
  .on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  })
  .on('blur', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });
```

```css
input.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

**Another example using space-separated list of events:**

```js
$('input')
  .on('focus blur', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });
```

```css
input.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You might use a simple CSS3 rule:

```
input:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$('input').on('focusin' function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('someClass')
});
$('input').on('focusout' function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('someClass')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you could attach event handlers to the focus and blur events.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/

```
$(someSelector).on('focus', function(evt) { 
//do stuff
})
```

and

```
$(someSelector).on('blur', function(evt) { 
//do stuff
})
```

Note that you can use focusin and focusout if you need to listen for event bubbling.